# How to concatenate mongodb object on a variable in foreach loop - PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, object, foreach

I am having a foreach loop, inside that data is fetching from mongodb
Here is a sample

```
foreach($result as $document)
    {
$response_object = $this->user_model->getdata($document['id']);
    }
```

$response_object holds the mongocursor object of last iteration in this example. I need make $response_object as object variable which has to concatenate the objects in foreach till iteration and store in $response_object.

Comment: could you elaborate more? For me it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: baboizk: $response_object is variable to hold the object; when it runs in foreach the last iteration value is only stored in the variable; I want to store each response through out the iteration in the single variable. Also the variable $response_object should be mongocursor object

Comment: you want to store each iteration in different variable or hold all iterations data in one variable?

Comment: Ilan Hasanov: In a single variable

Answer (score 0):

And why do you need a variable when you can use an array?

```
$listOfResponses = array();

foreach($result as $document)
   array_push($listOfResponses, $this->user_model->getdata($document['id']));
```

Comment: But, $listOfResponses is an array on the example. I am thinking to create an object variable to store all rather than array. Because, mongocursor object I am able to check its function like $listOfResponses->hasNext();

Comment: You can check in a loop if there's a next item available as well in the array.